# Easiest way to generate quadrature signal on PCB

Tags: pcb, rf, oscillator, high-frequency, quadrature

I have a chip which needs a quadrature LO. Specifications:

- Frequency range: 1.7 GHz - 2.5 GHz (wider range appreciated)
- Both I/Q differential (i.e. 4 wires in total)
- Each wire 1Vpp
- DC offset of 500mV (capable of driving 50 Ohm, i.e., 10-20mA)
- Matching is 50 Ohm but not perfect (S11 > -10dB)
- Jitter: hundreds of fs rms (like 400fs)
- Phase accuracy: ~1 deg
- *If possible*: Capability of fast (or even ultra fast) hopping/settling (around 10ns)
- Cost: "does not matter"
- Power: "does not matter"

For my current revision, I use an external signal generator which goes into a 90 Degree hybrid and enters the PCB via 2 SMA connectors (I and Q). Each of these channels go through an on-board 1:1 balun. An RF choke adds DC offset of 500mV.

However, this setup is clunky, the on-board balun (MABA-007871-CT1A40) does not even meet the specs. For my second revision, I would like to generate these signals on-board to simplify the setup.

An RFDAC (like AD9164: 16 Bit, 12 GPBS) would satisfy all requirements but getting this 165-pin BGA beast with its SERDES interface working takes me forever.

So if I relax the fast settling requirement I would assume there are solutions out there. However, I am unable to find any quadrature generators on DigiKey! (I can find I/Q Modulators or Demodulators but I need the generation).

Comment: How much harmonic distortion can you tolerate? I wonder about using a digital clock generator chip and then filtering off the harmonics.

Comment: Must it be a sine wave?

Comment: Two channels of DDS + two RF frequency multipliers. OR Two channels of high bandwidth DDS + up-conversion mixers. Each up-conversion mixer would receive 1.75 GHz CW + one of the DDS's. I'm not an RF engineer, but I think this could work.

Comment: Levels can be sorted out using pads if needed. If true differential signal is needed, you can use a balun on each signal.

Comment: @PeterGreen: It is a clock signal, hence HD is not an issue; the signal is rectified using inverters. However, digital clock generators usually don't satisfy 400fsrms? Also, the main question is about (simple) quadrature output.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: It is a clock signal, hence HD is not an issue; the signal is rectified using inverters. HOWEVER, it should be *close* to a sinusoid since a 2.5GHz square wave won't make it through the bondwire. And even if, it is prone to excessive ringing.

Comment: Do you have sideband suppression goals? or mixer-image suppression goals? I've seen sideband suppression vary 30+ dB based on phase accuracy and on-chip delay matching of + and - aluminum-path distances.

Answer (score 5):

### Fast flip flops make light work of 0 to 90

Since the target system can accept a non-sine-wave signal, the solution to this problem is actually rather simple -- generate a 3.4 to 5GHz differential *clock* signal (by hook or by crook, I don't care how you get it), and then use 2 DFFs in the classical quadrature generator configuration, as depicted below (image from [this article](http://www.markimicrowave.com/blog/top-7-ways-to-create-a-quadrature-90-phase-shift/)):

[image: DFF quadrature generator]

Considering that fast flip flops, such as the 10GHz [NB7V52M](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NB7V52M) have differential I/Os, we can elide the inverter (it becomes a differential transposition), yielding the resulting circuit (termination components not shown for clarity's sake):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK44Vw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Parts cost is a non-issue -- I seriously doubt you can get a 5GHz generator for less than the [cost](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/NB7V52MMNG/NB7V52MMNGOS-ND/2003325) of the two flip-flop ICs in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

A wideband analogue phase splitter can be made like this: -

[image]

The input stimulus comes from V1 and I and Q outputs are at Va and Vb. Providing you keep the two resistors at a value of \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ then you get a constant phase shift of exactly 90 degrees between Va and Vb.

So, for the implementation above, the bode diagram is: -

[image]

The only down side is that there are amplitude variations in Va and Vb across the frequency range. For instance, at 1.7 GHz, Va is about 2 dB higher than Vb. At 2.5 GHz, Vb is about 1.4 dB bigger than Va.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a passive **polyphase filter** like this one?

[image]

<sup>Image source: http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.msse.20120104.02.html</sup>